# Getting "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" - don't know why!

Tags: jquery

I've asked this question here before, but never got an answer. In Firebug, in the Console, I get 'ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined'. I have no clue why. Can anyone help?

Here is the page I'm working on: http://goinspire.com/jwrp-hotel-registration/

I can provide other code files from my site if it will help - please let me know which ones you want.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: How do I figure out why jQuery is not included in the page early enough? thank you!

Comment: two issues, none directly related to WordPress. You have code trying to use `jQuery` before jQuery is included in the page. The second issue is you have a file using `jquery` instead of `jQuery`.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed issue #2, but I don't know to fix #1. Would that be in one of the php template files?

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to WordPress, I guess moderators are in a good mood. Anyway this error can happen when a script that needs jQuery is enqueued before jQuery. The solution might be to use the parameter `$deps` of `wp_enqueue_script()` :

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, array('jquery'), $ver, $in_footer );;
```

[See this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

**EDIT :** See helgatheviking's answer. It might be due to a script added in `header.php` or a function hooked on `wp_head()` with a very high $priority (under 10)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't understand why this is not related to wp, but whatever. I added array('jquery') to where I'm enqueueing that script, but I still get the error in the console. Any advice?

Comment: I've edited answer. Do not forget to empty cache if your site cache for known users.

Comment: Do I need to register each script twice, then?

Comment: not at all. My mystake, I've put this on the wrong topic. Fixed now.

Comment: OK> I will empty the site cache and try again. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following code is trying to use jQuery before the jQuery library is loaded. Hard to say exactly where it is coming from, but it seems related to your form. If that is a custom form, maybe check in your theme's header.php? It is definitely not being enqueued properly and so I would guess it might be hard-coded.

```
<script>jQuery(function(){jQuery('#input_38_7').attr('placeholder','First Name');jQuery('#input_38_6').attr('placeholder','Last Name');jQuery('#input_38_2').attr('placeholder','Email');jQuery('#input_38_3').attr('placeholder','Phone Number');});</script>
```

Maybe try using a better form plugin? Both Ninja Forms and Gravity forms are excellent.

Comment: I'm actually using gravity forms, but it's possible that there are other things there (I inherited this site from another developer = fun!)

Comment: I just searched my entire site's files for '#input_38_7', and didn't find it! Odd!

Comment: I found similar stuff in wp-content\cache. Am I allowed to delete files in there?

Comment: So strange! I cleared out the cache, and I'm still seeing that error in the console. Any ideas where on earth it could  be coming from? Thanks!

Comment: Did you check your theme? Try reverting to TwentyFourteen for a second. Try searching your site's files for attr('placeholder') or just placeholder.

Comment: No error in 2011 theme. Just updated WP and reset all plugins, and it looks like the issue is gone.